# How to remove the fc-time from Fullcalendar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar v2.3.1 and I'm trying to remove the time as showed in attached screenshot.

I give the display:none to .fc-time class but anything happened.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Firstly, fullCalendar 2 is ancient history. It does not receive new features or even bug fixes any more. The newest version (v5) gives you a lot more flexibility and features. I would highly recommend upgrading, as you are several years behind the latest version.

Comment: Anyway, it's unclear how you ended up with the format shown, because it's not the default. Can we see your code please? Also, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/slotLabelFormat is the setting you should use to control the format of the date, there should be no need to mess about with CSS.

Comment: (N.B. I linked v3 documentation because, as the documentation itself says, v3 and v2 are almost the same API, and if you go to v2 docs it just takes you to v3 anyway.)